# airflow SparkKubernetesOperator cannot submit application to sparkoperator

Tags: python, apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-kafka, airflow

I have this error while testing the airflow with spark operator on kubernetes. Here is the dag file i use and the log i got from server. And i'm new in this stuff.

```
# dag_file.py
import os
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.spark_kubernetes import SparkKubernetesOperator
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.sensors.spark_kubernetes import SparkKubernetesSensor

default_args={
   'depends_on_past': False,
   'email': ['abcd@gmail.com'],
   'email_on_failure': False,
   'email_on_retry': False,
   'retries': 1,
   'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}
with DAG(
   'dag-spark',
   default_args=default_args,
   description='simple dag',
   schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
   start_date=datetime(2023, 3, 9),
   catchup=False,
) as dag:
   t1 = SparkKubernetesOperator(
       task_id='n-spark-pi',
       trigger_rule="all_success",
       depends_on_past=False,
       retries=2,
       application_file="write-hdfs.yaml",
       namespace="spark-operator",
       kubernetes_conn_id="kubernetes_default",
       api_group="sparkoperator.k8s.io",
       api_version="v1beta2",
       do_xcom_push=True,
       dag=dag
```

Expected: Spark application will run and i can see it with kubectl get pod
Actually Resulted: Spark application can't run and logs have these lines

```
2023-03-10 03:26:54.139
I0310 03:26:54.139500 10 webhook.go:552] Pod myseconddagnsparkpi.6b18d62fc88b488bbb92c27561c3f322 in namespace default is not subject to mutation
2023-03-10 03:26:54.137
I0310 03:26:54.137285 10 webhook.go:247] Serving admission request
```

```
# write-hdfs.yaml
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: write-hdfs-ngon
  namespace: spark-jobs
spec:
  type: Python
  pythonVersion: "3"
  mode: cluster
  image: "lighty55/myspark3:v3.1"
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  mainApplicationFile: local:///opt/spark/work-dir/write-hdfs.py
  sparkVersion: "3.2.1"
  restartPolicy:
    type: OnFailure
    onFailureRetries: 1
    onFailureRetryInterval: 10
    onSubmissionFailureRetries: 1
    onSubmissionFailureRetryInterval: 20
  driver:
    cores: 1
    coreLimit: "1200m"
    memory: "800m"
    labels:
      version: 3.2.1
    serviceAccount: spark
  executor:
    cores: 1
    instances: 1
    memory: "800m"
    labels:
      version: 3.2.1
```

Does anyone know what kind of error here and how to fix it?